# finding f(n) in a peculiar sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's think about a special sequence `f(n)`. In this sequence, when `a < b`, then `f(a) <= f(b)`.

The special property of this sequence is that f(n) is the number of times n appears in the sequence.

With this property in mind, we form this sequence given n:

```
n   = 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 6 , 7 , 8 , 9 , 10 , 11
f(n)= 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 4 , 5 ,  5 ,  5
```

the number 1 appears once in `f(n)`, number 2 appears twice in f(n), number 3 appears twice in f(n).

I have to formulate a function so that when given `n`, I can return `f(n)`.

I found an interesting pattern where in `f(n)` after the number 1, the next two numbers repeat one more than the previews number. so its like

```
22,33,444,555,6666,7777,88888,99999 ...
```

Maybe I can use recursion here? I am not well versed in recursion maybe someone can point me to the right direction.

Comment: I don't see any reason for recursion here. It seems like you should be able to solve it mathematically given the pattern you found.

Comment: Is `f(n)` meant to be self-referential like this? That value of `f(n)` is the number of times `n` appears in the sequence `f(n)`?

Comment: yes the value of f(n) is the number of times n appears in the sequence f(n)

Comment: So you need to figure out a function `f()` that satisfies that property? This sounds more appropriate for [math.se]. Once you determine the mathematical function, writing it in Python should be simple.

Comment: Wouldn't `f = lambda n: 0` satisfy the constraints (over the domain `n >= 1`)?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, but this sounds like a [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation)

Comment: I am currently trying to solve it mathematically. But I was thinking, since I know the pattern that maybe I can use loops? to start from one to the given n to get my answer. Or would that take too long once n becomes too big?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A001462 contains formulae, eg a(1) = 1; a(n+1) = 1 + a(n+1-a(a(n))). OEIS is often the best place to go when you have an integer sequence and want to understand or identify it.

Comment: Oh wow its a Golomb's sequence. Thank you @PaulHankin for this information. I'll be able to formulate somethings here

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! It may not be efficient but I manged to do it without recursion

```
def magicSequence(n):
    start=[1,2,2]
    i = 3
    if n == 1: return 1
    if n == 0: return None
    while len(start) < n:
        start += [i]*start[i-1]
        i += 1
    return start[n-1]
```

this code generates the sequence it self up until the required length of sequence. Then I simply return the value of the sequence on a specific index.